# NSPredicate to find out if Entity's instance has a parent?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have an Employee entity. Employees can be in a Department or they can NOT be in any department. (the employee would be the destination relationship of a department)

```
Department > Adam Charles
             John Smith
             Chris James



(no dept)    Gerry James
             Michael Lewis
```

How would I construct my NSPredicate to return an array of employees who:

- are in a department
- are not in any department (Gerry, Michael)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, hopefully [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2748449/793911) is the answer you are looking for.