# Fetch predicate: get all items with no relationship items from Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, fetch, predicate

I have an Entity called Group. Which has a to-many relationship to Group called parentGroup.

I want to query CD for all top level groups. (Ones that don't have a parent group).

I can't figure out what the predicate should be. I have tried:

```
fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parentGroup" == nil)

NSPredicate(format: "%K == nil", #keyPath(Group.parentGroup))

NSPredicate(format: "parentGroup" == %@, nil)
```

An old Obj-C post on a similar topic that didn't work: [iPhone SDK Core Data: Fetch all entities with a nil relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745994/iphone-sdk-core-data-fetch-all-entities-with-a-nil-relationship)

Thanks

Comment: Have you implemented an inverse for the relationship?  I just wonder whether this is a side effect of having no inverse.

Comment: What results do you get with these predicates? In what way are they failing?

Comment: Yeah I have an inverse. @TomHarrington the predicates aren't valid code or return all items even if they have a parent group. (Yes I'm adding the predicate to the fetch request.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution. The other predicates were failing because it was a to-many relationship.

```
fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parents.@count == 0")
```